# Is there a method to improve contour joining?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

I am performing a processing that involves segmentation, sometimes the external shape of the figure does not reach a good detection, however, that part is not possible to modify. I am looking for a method that allows me to join my contours as similar as possible to the figure, at the moment this union is very linear.

Do you have any idea? I leave below the images I am referring to.

Contour detection of the figure:

[image]

Contour join and fill:

[image]

Figure goal (approx.):

[image]

any method is welcome, thanks!

Comment: Can you explain, why the goal better suits the contour than the first join&fill?

Comment: @Micka I think OP wants to fit the "missing" corners with a spline. This is speculation, but can you try doing join-and-fill, then replacing linear segments with a spline curve (e.g. using the `shapely` library).

Comment: @Micka Yes, the problem is that it does not find continuity in the contour, so it makes the union as in a straight line.

Comment: For continuity use spline curves

Comment: Let me check, thanks a lot!